# Code syntax in python with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

can someone please tell me the difference between these following two notations, one is working, the other one isn't but they seem the same to me.

```
def GradientDescentCostTest():

    theta = numpy.array([0, 0, 0], numpy.float)
    features = numpy.array([[80, 20, 0], [65, 30, 1], [70, 23, 1]], numpy.float)
    values = numpy.array([20, 10, 14], numpy.float)    

    # This works and returns a value for cost:
    sumOfSquareErrors = numpy.square(numpy.dot(features, theta) - values).sum()
    cost = sumOfSquareErrors/(len(values)*2)

    # This doesn't work and returns value 0.0 for cost:
    cost = 1/(len(values)*2) * numpy.square(numpy.dot(features, theta) - values).sum()    

    return cost

print GradientDescentCostTest()
```

Thanks

Comment: sure can you provide enough to make your samples runnable (ie an example for all the undefined variables)

Comment: I learned [BODMAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations) at school.

Comment: added a full code example now, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1/(len(values)*2)` is equal to `0` because all operations are on integers. A simple fix is to instead use `1.0/(len(values)*2)`.